# Is it just me or does it look like this is graphing shapes similar to $r^t = |x|^t+|y|^t$?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, envelope

I wrote [a program](https://editor.p5js.org/hpestock/sketches/4q4H-kT1h) to cast some points out to a shape defined by lines and then connect any point to a certain amount of points down the shape with a line, and it looks like this is producing shapes on the inside of it that are very similar to
$$ 
|x|^t + |y|^t = |r|^t 
$$
shapes you might graph.

Can anyone explain what is going on here?

--In more detail, the program takes a set of lines for an input, in this case creating a square rotated 45 degrees, and then it casts a number of points from the origin of the area outwards, and they are saved once they hit any of the lines,

The program then draws lines from each of these points to points a certain distance down the shape.

Comment: Can you explain more about what your program does? This explanation seems rather incomplete.

Comment: I have edited the post, does this help?

Comment: You keep saying "a number of points", "a certain distance".  Are these constants set by the program?  Parameters that vary?  How are they determined?

Comment: The convex hull of some random selection of points on the interior of a square will always be better fit by some equation of this form. Basically you can tune how tightly they hug the corners by increasing $t$. This is a consequence of the fact that the $L^p$-norms become the $L^\infty$-norm in the limit.

Comment: The amount of points it changes is variable, it's set to increase slightly each frame, the number of points cast doesn't really change much, if you had it approach infinity it would just make the shape on the inside more well defined

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $$|x|^t+|y|^t=|r|^t,$$ represents a square when $t=1$, it represents a curved star like bounded figure if $0<t<1$. For $t=2$, it represents a circle. For $t>1$, it is a bounded region. For $t>>1$ it is like a square with rounded corners. For $r-1$ and $t=1/2,1,2,8$ see the figures below:

[image]

Comment: I don't follow, and I don't currently have a method of viewing the attached image, I'm using a laptop issued to me by my school and they have imgur restricted under the proxy filter, could you elaborate?